# Difference between #^{...} and ^{...} metadata in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

Consider

```
(defn f ^{:foo "bar"} [x] (* x x))
```

and

```
(defn g #^{:foo "bar"} [x] (* x x))
```

Both compile and run.

I have two questions: first, why do `(meta f)` and `(meta g)` produce only `nil`?  I would have expected them to produce `{:foo "bar"}`; i.o.w., am I just completely out to lunch on metadata and have I defined some kind of garbage out there?

Second, what is the difference between the two syntaces for the metadata?  It looks like the second one is a "[tagged literal](http://clojure.org/reader)," something to do with [edn, the extended data notation](https://github.com/edn-format/edn), but I can't quite noodle it out without some more context or examples.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `#^` metadata reader macro [was replaced with](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/1.2.x/changes.txt#L89) `^` in clojure 1.2. While there is currently no difference between the two, the old form is deprecated and you should be using `^` exclusively.

The metadata literal should come *before* the item it is to be attached to:

```
(defn ^{:foo "bar"} f [x] (* x x))
```

Another thing to keep in mind is that the metadata in the above definition isn't attached to the function, it is attached to the `var` that refers to the function. You can get the metadata of the `f` `var` with:

```
(meta (var f))
```

Or using the `var` reader macro:

```
(meta #'f)
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer.  I'm looking at `(doc defn)` and it says the name comes before the metadata, unless I am mis-reading the doc: "clojure.core/defn
([name doc-string? attr-map? [params*] prepost-map? body] [name doc-string? attr-map? ([params*] prepost-map? body) + attr-map?])"

Comment: `attr-map` is a special feature of the `defn` macro which is supposed to make attaching metadata to the var being defined easier. When using `attr-map`, you shouldn't prefix the map with `^` (`(defn f {:foo "bar"} [] :baz)`). I haven't really seen this used anywhere, using the `^` reader macro is much more common. I'm guessing `attr-map` was useful in older versions of clojure when working with metadata was less pretty, but these days using the `^{:foo "bar}` form is more idiomatic and more general (you can place it before any object that can hold metadata).